# Undetected Chrome driver getting banned

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have this function. And I am using undetected chrome driver python.

```
def getDriver(n):


    options = ChromeOptions()
   
    driver = Chrome(options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://www.mister-auto.it")
    time.sleep(10)
    
    driver.get("https://www.mister-auto.it/pompa-acqua-kit-cinghia-poly-v/ina/529-0370-30/")
    
    s = input("Slide the slider!")
    
    
    return driver
```

When the Chrome window opens, it asks me to solve the captcha. I am doing it manually. As soon as, when I solve the captcha manually. Website block me.

The things I have tried:

- Headless
- Proxy
- User-agent.

Note:
This code works fine for other domain of this website.

Comment: Other domain of this website? This one is on "under attack" mode which means you have to solve the captcha